# How to Overcome Blurriness in Path and Canvas Drawings in .NET MAUI?

Tags: c#, .net, xaml, maui, scale

I'm currently working on a project using .NET MAUI and utilizing the Path and Canvas components to draw various shapes and squiggly lines. However, I'm encountering an issue with blurriness when scaling these drawings. It seems that there is a loss of quality, resulting in less crisp and clear visuals.This issue is not present on Android and iOS platforms

Is this blurriness a default behavior in .NET MAUI, or is there a way to overcome it and achieve sharper rendering of the drawings? I've tried adjusting parameters and settings, but haven't been able to find a satisfactory solution.[Like this I'm adding the shapes](https://i.stack.imgur.com/do870.png)

Here's a summary of the approaches I've tried so far:

Utilizing handlers to manipulate the drawings.
Experimenting with RenderTransform to adjust the scaling.
Adjusting various parameters and settings.

I'm still unable to achieve the desired level of clarity in the drawings, particularly on Mac where accessing the path in the canvas within handlers poses a challenge and on Windows I can't use handlers(ContentScaleFactor).

Comment: A short single line of code and you made a screenshot of that and cropped the picture instead of just copy pasting it into the editor here?

Comment: Do you use SkiaSharp or  [Graphics](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/user-interface/graphics/?view=net-maui-8.0)?

Comment: public void Draw(ICanvas canvas, RectF dirtyRect)
{
    canvas.StrokeColor = Colors.Red;
    canvas.StrokeSize = 6;
    canvas.DrawLine(10, 10, 90, 100);
}

<GraphicsView Grid.Row="2" x:Name="lineC" Drawable="{StaticResource lineDrawable}"
      HeightRequest="120"
      WidthRequest="400" />

Comment: I used Graphics
xmlns:graphics="clr-namespace:Microsoft.Maui.Graphics;assembly=Microsoft.Maui.Graphics"

Comment: Do you mean using this [Scale transform](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/user-interface/graphics/transforms?view=net-maui-8.0#scale-transform) will cause blur? But I didn't see much blur using sample code.

Comment: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1DqMqiJxeBzyls-Pc10G0U2IbDccjR7k9/view?usp=sharing   Please see this sample

Comment: Thanks for your response. I add an answer below and find a workaround. Please take a look.

Answer (score 0):

That may relate to a known issue [[MAC/iOS] Contents are blurred with scaling](https://github.com/dotnet/maui/issues/9420). You may follow up this issue.

The workaround is using [Scale transform](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/user-interface/graphics/transforms?view=net-maui-8.0#scale-transform).

Based on your code, I made a demo. For convenience, I use [Preferences](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/platform-integration/storage/preferences?view=net-maui-8.0&tabs=android) to store the scale value.

Each time click the button, I update the new scale value and redraw the line,

```
    private void OnZoomInClicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var value = Preferences.Get("scale", 1.0);
        var newvalue = value * 1.2;
        Preferences.Set("scale", newvalue);
        lineC.Invalidate();
    }
```

This is Line class,

```
public void Draw(ICanvas canvas, RectF dirtyRect)
{
    var scale = Preferences.Get("scale", 1.0);

    canvas.StrokeColor = Colors.Red;
    canvas.StrokeSize = 6;
    canvas.Scale((float)scale, (float)scale);
    canvas.DrawLine(10, 10, 90, 100);
}
```

This is a small demo and not much blur during the scale transform.

Hope it helps!